# How to prevent an input field from accepting other numbers than 0 or 1?

Tags: angular

I am building a bin to dec converter to learn Angular and I am having troubles preventing the input field from receiving/displaying other digits than 0 or 1.

This is what I have so far:

*my component html file*

```
<form [formGroup]="numberForm">

<input (keyup)="onKey($event)" id="number" placeholder="" value="">
   <button (click)="convert()">Convert</button>
</form>

<div class="output">{{ output }}</div>
```

*my component ts file*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
selector: 'app-converter',
templateUrl: './converter.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./converter.component.css']
})

export class ConverterComponent implements OnInit {
numberForm;
values;
output;

constructor(
private formBuilder: FormBuilder
) {

this.numberForm = this.formBuilder.group({
number: ''

})
}

ngOnInit() {}

convert() {
    this.output = parseInt(this.values, 2);
}

onKey(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    if((event.keyCode < 48) || (event.keyCode > 49)) {
        alert('Only 1 and 0 please!');
        return false;
    }
this.values = event.target.value;

}
}
```

This kinda works in the sense that the alert message fires but the invalid digit is still added to the input field and I am not sure how to fix that.

**What have I tried**
I have tried using the keyDown event but for the first execution, console.log(event.target.value) will output null even though I enter a valid digit.

Comment: Please, format your code.

Comment: @vulp Is this better?

Comment: A bit, but still could be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the `input` event:

```
<input (input)="onInput($event)" ...>
```

If you detect that any character other than `0` or `1` is present in the field, you put back the previous valid value. In addition to keyboard inputs, that method takes into account text pasted in the field, and it allows to use the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key, the arrow keys, and other text editing keys.

```
binaryValue = "";

onInput(event: Event) {
  const element = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  const newValue = element.value;
  if (/[^01]/.test(newValue)) {        // If any character other than 0 or 1 is present
    element.value = this.binaryValue;  // Put back the previous valid value
    alert("Only 1 and 0 please!");
  } else {
    this.binaryValue = newValue;       // Only 0 and 1 are present, accept the new value
  }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j9wmgr?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `event.preventDefault()` before returning false to stop the event, and use the `keydown` in place of `keyup` event. Or `input` event if using new browsers (IE doesn't support)

Comment: Add it where exactly? Inside the onKey if statement? If yes, that doesn't work in the sense that I can still enter 2,3 or any other digit.